# cvConvexityDefects in OpenCV 2.X / C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, convex-hull

I'm using OpenCV 2.2 and I need to determine convexity defects of a convex hull. I can't find anything on convexity defects in the [documentation](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/cpp/index.html) which makes me wonder if it is still supported in OpenCV 2.X or if it was renamed?

Anyways, I tried using the C function

```
CvSeq* cvConvexityDefects(const CvArr* contour, const CvArr* convexhull, CvMemStorage* storage=NULL )
```

However, I'm not able to convert my `std::vector<Point> hull` into `CvArr`. The `CvArr` parameters to `cvConvexityDefects` should be 1-dimensional and continuous array of int's, which I had no success in creating (tried casting, manual copying into a CvSeq structure, ...).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem than you but I managed to resolve it! Check my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806637/convexity-defects-c-opencv

I hope this could help you!