# Extracting the fingers from the hand

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gesture-recognition, convex-hull

I am using this code to **extract the finger**s when users show their hands to the camera.

The following error is being thrown after inserting these lines to find the convexity.

```
     if (contours[i].size() >3 )
       {
        cout<<"inside"<<endl;
        convexityDefects(contours[i], hull[i], defects[i]);
       }
```

**And the error is :**

inside
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (hull.checkVector(1, CV_32S) > 2) in convexityDefects, file C:/slave/builds/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1971

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
                                                                             Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  C:/slave/builds/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:1971: error: (-215) hull.checkVector(1, CV_32S) > 2 in function convexityDefects

**Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?**

**Code:**

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

 #include <iostream>

 #include <stdio.h>

 #include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 Mat src; Mat src_gray;
 int thresh = 147;
 int max_thresh = 255;
 RNG rng(12345);

 /// Function header
 void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {

   src = imread( "D:\\a.jpg", 1 );



   /// Convert image to gray and blur it
   resize(src,src,Size(640,480),0,0,INTER_LINEAR);
   cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
   blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

   /// Create Window
   char* source_window = "Knuckle Extractor";
   namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( source_window, src );

//   createTrackbar( " Threshold:",  source_window, &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
   thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

   waitKey(0);
   return(0);
 }

 /** @function thresh_callback */
 void thresh_callback(int, void* )
 {
   Mat src_copy = src.clone();
   Mat threshold_output;
   vector<vector<Point> > contours;
   vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

   /// Detect edges using Threshold
   threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY||CV_THRESH_OTSU );

  // imshow("Grey",src_gray);
   imshow("Threshold",threshold_output);

   /// Find contours
//   findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
//findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0) );
findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

   /// Find the convex hull object for each contour
   vector<vector<Point> >hull( contours.size() );
   vector<vector<Vec4i> >defects( contours.size() );

   for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
        {  
         convexHull( Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false ); 
         if (contours[i].size() >3 )
           {
            cout<<"inside"<<endl;
            convexityDefects(contours[i], hull[i], defects[i]);
           }
        }



   /// Draw contours + hull results
   Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
   for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {
        Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
        drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
       drawContours( drawing, hull, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
      }

   /// Show in a window
   namedWindow( "Result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Result", drawing );
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem (or at least the main one I can see), is the way you construct your contours. You should use:

```
vector<vector<int> >hull( contours.size() );
```

Instead of:

```
vector<vector<Point> >hull( contours.size() );
```

This is because the `convexityDefects` function only works on convex hulls represented by a series of indices rather than a series of points.

Comment: Thanks roger for your response. I modified the code as you suggested and now i am getting " OpenCV Error:Assertion failed(npoints >0) in drawContours file C:/slave/builds/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1821
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.Please contact the application's support team for more information.Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what(): C:/slave/builds/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:1821: error: (-215) npoints > 0 in function drawContours'

Comment: But this time, the for loop iterates for two times.

Comment: @user2881263 yes, that's a common issue - `convexityDefects` requires indices, while `drawContours` requires points. A quick fix is to extract both - use the indices for the convexity defects and the points for drawing, you just need to call `convexHull` twice (one for each type of output).

Comment: Thanks roger. Your solution worked for me. Unfortunately, i don't have enough points to upvote your answer. BTW. Can you also tell me how to extract the Convexity defect points to draw a circle?

Comment: @user2881263 ok, you have more rep now and you'll get another 2 if [you choose to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (no obligation though). If you have a new question, it's better to ask it with an example rather than continue in comments.

Comment: See this answer for working C++ source code that calls convexityDefects properly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35190031/763355

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped.