# OpenCV C++ cv::convexityDefects error

Tags: c++, opencv, convex-hull

```
vector<Point> hull;
vector<Point> defects;
convexHull(Mat(largest),hull,false);
convexityDefects(largest,hull,defects);
```

**largest* is my largest contour in the image

But the convexityDefects gives me this error "Assertion failed (hull.checkVector(1, CV_32S) > 2)". Someone please help me, I do not want to resort to using C solution.

EDITED

```
vector<int> hull;
vector<Point> defects;
convexHull(Mat(largest),hull,false);

vector<vector<int>> testhull;
testhull.push_back(hull);
convexityDefects(largest,testhull,defects);
```

I tried making it with the type `vector<vector<int>>` before passing it to convexityDefects but convexityDefects is still giving me error "Assertion failed (ptnum > 3)..".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `convexityDefects` has to be the type of `vector<vector<int>`, while yours is `vector<Point>`.

Comment: I have made some changes to my codes, please check again on the first post. Thanks.

Comment: @user1434759 I have googled answer to all your problems very quickly. Did you try to google before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620981/calculating-convexitydefects-using-opencv-2-4-in-c

Answer (score 4):

for hull you should use a vector of vectors like this:

```
vector<vector<Point>> hullsP( contours.size() );
vector<vector<int> > hullsI(contours.size());
```

and pass the "int" type to covexityDefects.like this :

```
vector<vector<Vec4i>> convdefect(contours.size());

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{ 
    convexHull( Mat(contours[i]), hullsP[i], false );
    convexHull( Mat(contours[i]), hullsI[i], false );       
    if(hullsI[i].size() > 3 )
        convexityDefects(contours[i],hullsI[i],convdefect[i]);
}
```