# "Assertion failed (ptnum > 3)" in OpenCV 2.4.2 for iOS when calculating convexityDefects, unable to get one seamless contour

Tags: ios, opencv

I've looked at and tried to solution to the similar question at [Calculating convexityDefects using OpenCV 2.4 in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620981/calculating-convexitydefects-using-opencv-2-4-in-c), but his solution doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
// Get contours
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
findContours(inputMat, contours, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

vector<vector<cv::Point> > hulls(contours.size());
vector<vector<int> > intHulls(contours.size());
vector<vector<Vec4i> > defects(contours.size());

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hulls[i]);
    convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), intHulls[i]);
    convexityDefects(contours[i], intHulls[i], defects[i]);
}
```

I always get:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ptnum > 3) in convexityDefects, file /Users/user/slave/ios_framework/src/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 1969
```

So I went and downloaded the source to check out contours.cpp, line 1969.

```
1965 void cv::convexityDefects( InputArray _points, InputArray _hull, OutputArray _defects )
1966 {
1967     Mat points = _points.getMat();
1968     int ptnum = points.checkVector(2, CV_32S);
1969     CV_Assert( ptnum > 3 );
```

It looks like it's trying to make a Mat of the contour points, then it checks the Mat for... something? There wasn't any documentation at http://docs.opencv.org/ for checkVector, but googling found [this documentation](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_mat.html#a39541d4dbd7fafbfae93f1737e51ffbc):

```
int cv::Mat::checkVector    (   int     elemChannels,
    int     depth = -1,
    bool    requireContinuous = true 
    )        const

returns N if the matrix is 1-channel (N x ptdim) or ptdim-channel (1 x N) or (N x 1); negative number otherwise
```

After reading that a few times, I'm still completely lost and unsure about what would be causing this error or what I can do to fix it. I've been trying to figure out this whole convexityDefects() problem myself for the last week and haven't had any luck at all.

Edit: I just double-checked a few things to be safe.

My input mat is always 100 cols x 120 rows, just like it should be. However, the contours, which I assumed would be as smooth and continuous as they look on the screen, are apparently not. When I convert them to mats and check the size, they're almost always always 1 col by XXX rows. So I guess my problem is that I have to get a two-dimensional contour -- is there a way to join them together? They look seamless on my screen.

Edit 2: Even drawing the contours on a proper mat and passing that gives me the same "Assertion failed (ptnum > 3)" error. I really don't know what to do now.

Comment: What about googling question before asking? Here's exactly the same problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840752/opencv-c-cvconvexitydefects-error

Comment: There is no solution there. That's the same problem in the same situation -- my second argument is indeed vector <vector<int> > as the specifications say it should be.

Ironically, on the comment you just linked now, you linked the comment that I reference at the very top of my problem explanation. Apparently you didn't read what I wrote?

Comment: you call `convexityDefects` with type `<vector<int>` not with `vector<vector<int> >`...

Comment: And also links are not the same...

Comment: @Astor, you linked to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840752/opencv-c-cvconvexitydefects-error) in your initial comment; I went there to look at the solution and found that there, you linked to [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840752/opencv-c-cvconvexitydefects-error), which is exactly what I looked at and linked at the top. BECAUSE the solution there isn't working, I asked my own question with more details.

Changing my call to `convexityDefects(contours[i], intHulls, defects[i]);` to provide a vector<vector<int> > doesn't help; I get the same error.

Comment: I posed an answer to this question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620981/calculating-convexitydefects-using-opencv-2-4-in-c

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you! That's so obvious, now that I think of it... it's just something you'd expect to be handled gracefully by the function itself or mentioned in the documentation. I actually ended up writing a wrapper for the old C function. :(