# Open CV convexity defects drawing

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to join the convexity defects in openCV with the help of a line.
The convexity defects are stored in defects using vector>
How do i access the elements of a particular defect(4 element integer array)
Suppose i am drawing the liness using

```
for (int i = 0; i < defects.size(); i++){
            line(frame,\\startindex;\\endindex,color,thickness,linetype);
        }
```

How do i get the start index and end index for  paricular defect?
I have gone through similar questions but cant seem to understand

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV convexity defects drawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354150/opencv-convexity-defects-drawing)

Comment: Can you please help me with the question! Yea  the 2 are almost same.. However unanswered