# I want to find the biggest contour of the image

Tags: android, opencv

I want to find the convex and get convexity defects for the biggest contour .Here my code for finding the biggest contour.I use opencv for android.Can someone guild me please.

```
       Imgproc.cvtColor (inputFrame.rgba(), mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb, 4);
        Core.inRange(mIntermediateMat, new Scalar(1, 133, 77), new Scalar(255, 173, 127), mGray);
        Imgproc.erode(mGray,mGray, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(4,4)));        
        Imgproc.dilate(mGray, mGray, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(4, 4)));
        Imgproc.blur(mGray, mGray, new Size(3.0, 3.0));
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(mGray, mcontour, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, 1);
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        maxContourArea=0;
        contours= new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(mcontour, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) 
        {
               contour = contours.get(idx);

             double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
              if (contourarea > maxContourArea ) 
              {

                       maxContourArea = contourarea;
                       maxAreaIdx = idx;

              }
        }

        if(maxContourArea>1000)
        {
        Imgproc.drawContours ( mRgba, contours, maxAreaIdx, new Scalar(120,120,120),2);
        }
        contours.clear();
```

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358401/5008845)

Answer (score 0):

there are functions about

`cv::convexityDefects()` Finds the convexity defects of a contour

`cv::isContourConvex()` Tests a contour convexity

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html

Comment: I got it..Thank you eveyone.