# Transform a vector<vector<Point> > X into a IplImage* or cv::Mat*

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have a `vector<vector<Point> >` X but I need to pass it to the function `cvConvexityDefects` that takes in input a `CvArr*`.

I have already read the topic [Convexity defects C++ OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806637/convexity-defects-c-opencv). It takes in input these variables:

```
vector<Point>& contour, vector<int>& hull, vector<Point>& convexDefects
```

I cannot get the solution to work because I have a hull parameter that is a `vector<Point>` and I don't know how to transform it in a `vector<int>`.

So there are now two questions! :)

How can I convert a `vector<vector<Point> >` into a `vector<int>`?

Thanks in advance, have a good day!:)

Comment: Which version of OpenCV do you use?

Comment: 2.3.1, last one...downloaded from the site http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::for_each` and an accumulating object:

```
class AccumulatePoints
{
public:
    AccumulatePoints(std::vector<int>& accumulated)
    : m_accumulated(accumulated)
    {
    }

    void operator()(const std::vector<Point>& points)
    {
        std::for_each(points.begin(), points.end(), *this);
    }

    void operator()(const Point& point)
    {
        m_accumulated.push_back(point.x);
        m_accumulated.push_back(point.y);
    }
private:
    std::vector<int>& m_accumulated;
};
```

Used like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> accumulated;
    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> hull;

    std::for_each(hull.begin(), hull.end(), AccumulatePoints(accumulated));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank oyu so much :) that's perfect! just a thing: i comment the line m_accumulated.push_back(point.z) because there are no point.z variable in the point object (just point.x and point.y). thanks again

Comment: @MarcoMaisto I don't know OpenCV so it was just a guess. Have fixed.