# FindConvexityDefect Memory leak

Tags: opencv, memory-leaks

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 and I found that the function ConvexityDeffects is not available so I found someone here on stackoverflow writing it's implementation for this version
Link: [Convexity defects C++ OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806637/convexity-defects-c-opencv) 
and when I tried to implement it just when the program started I got memory leak and the whole pc stopped working.

the code of it

```
void HandDetection::findConvexityDefects(vector<Point>& contour, vector<int>& hull, vector<Point>& convexDefects){
if(hull.size() > 0 && contour.size() > 0){
CvSeq* contourPoints;
CvSeq* defects;
CvMemStorage* storage;
CvMemStorage* strDefects;
CvMemStorage* contourStr;
CvConvexityDefect *defectArray = 0;

strDefects = cvCreateMemStorage();
defects = cvCreateSeq( CV_SEQ_KIND_GENERIC|CV_32SC2, sizeof(CvSeq),sizeof(CvPoint), strDefects );

//We transform our vector<Point> into a CvSeq* object of CvPoint.
contourStr = cvCreateMemStorage();
contourPoints = cvCreateSeq(CV_SEQ_KIND_GENERIC|CV_32SC2, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), contourStr);
for(int i=0; i<(int)contour.size(); i++) {
    CvPoint cp = {contour[i].x,  contour[i].y};
    cvSeqPush(contourPoints, &cp);
}

//Now, we do the same thing with the hull index
int count = (int)hull.size();
//int hullK[count];
int* hullK = (int*)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){hullK[i] = hull.at(i);}
CvMat hullMat = cvMat(1, count, CV_32SC1, hullK);

//We calculate convexity defects
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
defects = cvConvexityDefects(contourPoints, &hullMat, storage);
defectArray = (CvConvexityDefect*)malloc(sizeof(CvConvexityDefect)*defects->total);
cvCvtSeqToArray(defects, defectArray, CV_WHOLE_SEQ);
//printf("DefectArray %i %i\n",defectArray->end->x, defectArray->end->y);

//We store defects points in the convexDefects parameter.
for(int i = 0; i<defects->total; i++){
    CvPoint ptf;
    ptf.x = defectArray[i].depth_point->x;
    ptf.y = defectArray[i].depth_point->y;
    convexDefects.push_back(ptf);
}

//We release memory
cvReleaseMemStorage(contourStr);
cvReleaseMemStorage(strDefects);
cvReleaseMemStorage(storage);
}}
```

So please can someone tell me Where is the problem ?

Comment: That you're using obsolete C syntax

Comment: I Tried to implement some functions like cvCreateMemStorage but i didn't found any function like this in c++ so what's the solution ?!

Comment: std::vector, or cv::Mat

Comment: Also, unless you have some strict constraints  you should update to opencv 3.0

Comment: I couldn't understand How Mat or Vector could help me , my problem is in the functions itself